# SQL query to make a column of numbers a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to convert a column of doubles in a big string:

Something like:

```
att1
----------
123.2
3.6
6.77
23.43
4.78
7.6
123.2
9.6
1.77
3.43
24.78
76.6
411.5
346.5
975.75
162.788
4.5
16.2
324.5
746.5
975.75
12.788
24.5
6.2


to

string = "
123.2,
3.6,
6.77,
23.43,
4.78,
7.6,
123.2,
9.6,
1.77,
3.43,
24.78,
76.6,
411.5,
346.5,
975.75,
162.788,
4.5,
16.2,
324.5,
746.5,
975.75,
12.788,
24.5,
6.2
";
```

Comment: yes. question asked many times on SO

Comment: I think @Bohemian meant which DBMS -- MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.

Comment: Are you using any programming language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @List varchar(max)

select @List = isnull(@List + ',', '') + cast(ColumnName as varchar)
from MyTable

print @List
```

For example:

```
declare @List varchar(max)

select @List = isnull(@List + ',', '') + cast(object_id as varchar)
from sys.objects

print @List
```

or

```
select stuff(
    (select ',' + cast(object_id as varchar)
    from sys.objects
    for xml path('')),
    1, 1, '')
```

Comment: One more question.... Is it possible to tell SQL Server to do this for a specific column, based by an index... or does it have to be column name?

Comment: @cMinor - Has to be column name. However, using dynamic SQL you can get column name by index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best solution, but I've encountered a similar problem before. Using SQL Server, I just parsed the data into an XML string and then replaced out the actual XML. This turned it into a comma-separated list of values.

```
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            (SELECT
                some_field AS [data()]
            FROM
                some_table
            FOR
                XML PATH ('label'))
        ,'</label><label>',',')
    ,'</label>','')
,'<label>','')
```