# All columns in a table to string SQL

Tags: sql-server, string

How to make multiple columns a string in SQL

Following a **single column to string** by [@Alex Aza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366640/sql-query-to-make-a-column-of-numbers-a-string):

```
 select stuff(
    (select ',' + cast([colum_name] as varchar)
    from [dbtest].[dbo].[table]
    for xml path('')),
    1, 1, '')
```

How to use that to get **all columns in a table a string**?
I was thinking using dynamic SQL....

So for example

```
col1  col2 col3
---------------
1    7    13 
2    8    14
3    9    15
4   10    16
5   11    17
6   12    18
```

(this results something like: `1,2,3,4,5,6` )

How to make it Return:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be, you can try something like this.

```
SELECT STUFF(
                    (
                        SELECT  ',' + CAST([col] AS VARCHAR)
                        FROM
                        (
                            SELECT col1 AS col FROM [dbtest].[dbo].[table] UNION
                            SELECT col2 AS col FROM [dbtest].[dbo].[table] UNION
                            SELECT col3 AS col FROM [dbtest].[dbo].[table] 
                        ) alldata
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    )
                ,   1
                ,   1
                ,   ''
            )
```

With sample data in the table like this...

[image: Data]

query output would be as following:

[image: Output]

Comment: I found this very useful, but, do you know a way to do that when you do not know the column names??I guess this is only possible with dynamic SQL...

Comment: @Alright I modified a little your code adding ALL, in the `UNION` because I was getting unordered results. Thank you

Comment: @cMinor: not knowing the column names makes it ever so tricky, but doable. See my post and let me know if its at all helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This was such a unique request I just had to give it a shot. It is possible to concatenate the csv without prior knowledge of column names (albeit, using very poor performing xquery tricks).  A dynamic query of UNIONs is far simpler to test and maintain, but here's how it could be done:

```
declare @t table (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

-- test data
insert into @t
select distinct 
        number,
        number+10,
        number+20
from master..spt_values where number between 1 and 10

select * from @t;
--

declare @x xml;
set @x = (select * from @t for xml path('r'));

;with c_ (s, r)
as  (   select  p.n.query('data(.)').value('.', 'varchar(10)'), 
                p.n.query('local-name(..)').value('.','varchar(10)')
        from    @x.nodes('r//.')p(n)
    )
select [csv] = stuff(
    (   select top 100 percent ','+s
        from    c_ 
        where   r = 'r'
        order
        by      len(s), s
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'');
```